# How can I force my companion to focus on healing instead of attacking enemies?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I want my companion(Mako) to focus on only healing me but she keeps attacking people. How can I get her to only heal me and not attack? If she focused on healing I would be a lot better off. Does anyone know what to set to do this. I also keep turning off her attacking abilities and they keep turning back on. How can I prevent that?

EDIT:

They fixed this issue in the new 1.1.0 release!!!!! I listed the bug fixes below.

Bug Fixes

- Companions will now sell trash items when requested, regardless of
  group size.
- Companion healing abilities no longer apply a permanent green effect 
  on the character.
- Fixed an issue that caused Companion Characters to sometimes have the
  incorrect appearance in cinematics.
- **Companion abilities that have been disabled by the player no longer toggle back on when the companion is re-summoned.**
- Corrected an issue that caused the indicator that a companion wants
  to talk to you to disappear.
- Companions no longer need to be re-summoned after selling trash items
  if the player mounts a vehicle after dispatching them.
- Traveling from a Contested Area to a Contested Region now causes
  companions to be unsummoned correctly.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that this falls under the broad category of 'Things that Are Broken In The Old Republics UI.' Related: My tank companion refuses to stay in tank stance, and the Cover Bar is reenabled seemingly at random no matter how many times I turn it off. Best you can do is probably watching like a hawk to make sure that those offensive skills are turned off and stay off.

Comment: It's driving me crazy, but I just got her to heal me long enough to pass the quest I was on so I am happy for a few minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In Theory** You should be able to do this by turning off auto-cast on all of your companions offensive abilities. You can do this by expanding their action bar (click the **+** on the right hand side of the 4 button action bar in their unit frame, at the bottom left of your screen.) See that green square in the top right corner of each spell? That's auto-cast. Right clicking on the spell will turn that off, and the square will become empty (black). Once auto-cast is off for a spell, your companion should never use it unless you specifically command them to (by actively clicking on that spell from their bar).

The reason this answer starts with *in theory* however, is because *in practice*, your companion will sometimes have all of their healing abilities on cooldown (or you will be topped off), at which point they might perform their basic attack.

Comment: That is the problem, the auto-cast keeps turning back on. I will need healing and the companion keeps attacking. In battle turning off auto-cast can be thousands of damage.

Comment: Khem Val turns his Consume Essence ability back on every time you summon him.  I was rather hoping they'd push an update today to fix  things like that.

Comment: @Powerlord Patch tomorrow, but autocast bugs doesn't seem to be in the notes.

Comment: In my experience its not for totally arbitrary and unknowable reasons. It seems to be (from memory) every time you die, every time you use a lift or fast travel. Every time a loading screen appears (game start being the most obvious). Every time there is a cutscene (unconfirmed personally but a friend suggested it did). All in all a pain in the ass and just far too frequent to be practically worth the bother. :(