# How can I make my companion focus on healing another player?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So, I'm a Vanguard in the level 30s and a friend has just got the game and started playing. I've run through a few Flashpoints and Heroics with him for fun, and and to help him through until we're an equivalent enough level to team up and adventure together properly. Being tank spec'd, I can pretty much stroll through these areas taking only single-digit damage, letting him do a lot of the work while I just soak up the damage.

Occasionally he'll take a stray hit from an AoE or catch an unwanted add before I can grab aggro, and as neither of us are healers I've brought Elara Dorne along for support but she insists on concentrating on healing my 1 or 2% damage and ignoring my friend's 40 or 50% damage most of the time. Short of manually targeting my friend and clicking Elara's healing abilities on the companion bar myself for each heal, is there any way I can get her to focus on him?

Note *superficially similar to this previous question, except that I want them to heal someone else, not me: [How can I force my companion to focus on healing instead of attacking enemies?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45480/how-can-i-force-my-companion-to-focus-on-healing-instead-of-attacking-enemies)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers there does seem to be a priority system in place but I don't know of anyway to change that.

However a possible way to help in your situation is to set your friend as your focus target and put your companions heal ability in a keybound quick slot.

You set a focus target by selecting another character (friend, enemy or npc) and pressing ALT-F (the default binding). You will see you have a new player icon and health bar on your screen. Now pressing End (again, the default binding) will cause your next ability to target your focus target.

I haven't tested but pressing End and then your companions heal would cast it on your target.

Comment: Aahhhh, how have I not heard of the focus target system before? Will have to try this out later.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to make your companion focus healing on a particular target.
All you can do is to disable all offensive abilities and turn on companion's healing stance (can't remember the exact name now).

From what I have observed, healing priority is decided by current health level and if it's the comapnion itself or a player (all players in group seem to have more or less the same priority, but self heal is higher in prio, which is kinda annoying when my Mako is at 60% hp, me at 20 and she heals herself)

Comment: Thanks, it seems my suspicions are true then. Will leave a bit longer before accepting in case anyone has any evidence/advice to the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make them focus on other players unless you manually click on them, although you can choose to make them only heal. Click on your companion and choose companion side bar then right click on the non healing abilities.