# How do I stop C2-N2 from attacking?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

As a Smuggler/Gunslinger, I have no healing ability but my ship droid C2-N2.  I do cybertech, so he's very well equipped.  Trouble is, C2-N2 will run in and *punch* opponents drawing aggro to himself.  This means he wastes healing on himself and dies.  I'd like him to stop that.

C2-N2 has [no attack spells to turn off](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45480/how-can-i-force-my-companion-to-focus-on-healing-instead-of-attacking-enemies).  Short of setting him passive, and having to manually cast his healing spells, how can I stop C2-N2 from attacking enemies?

Comment: Alternative Title: How do I get my robot to stop picking fights he can't win?

Comment: C2-N2 has an inability to breakdown alcohol due to his robotic nature. Don't let his polite sober form deceive you. Back at the ship he occasionally likes to hit the bottle when you don't have him run missions. This makes him a mean drunk and aggressive. You must manually and explicitly tell him to be passive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the ship droids now behave identically to any other companion, and coupled with the fact that companions no longer use gear to gain stats this is no longer a concern.

Comment: @matthewread Ooor you could post that as an answer and I can credit you for answering.

Comment: No, I don't see the point in keeping this around if it's no longer useful.

Comment: @MatthewRead You can do both! Just accept my edit to your answer.

Comment: You're allowed to self-answer a question, but please don't suggest an edit that changes an answer so drastically.  That's not at all what edits are for.  As such, I have rejected it.

Comment: @Frank It's his own words. I'm trying to give him credit.

Comment: Which he doesn't want to add to his answer.  Which is his perogative.

Comment: @Frank If it's *his* prerogative, why did *you* reject it? :P Well, this is all getting needlessly complicated. If it's that important to y'all I'll close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is that you can't, at least not right now.  It seems the latest update exacerabated this so hopefully they patch it back.  Or give him more abilities so that he can continue casting rather than punching during cooldowns.  However, his healing is much more likely to draw aggro than his pitifully weak punches; hitting the enemy once should be enough to draw aggro back to you for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Give him a gun. That way he'll do ranged attacks instead of punches, which makes him slightly less prone to get his face dented than running into melee range.

Answer (score -1):

Although he can equip a generator in his offhand, there is no weapon he will equip in his main. And you will notice in companion abilities, he has no weapon proficiencies, either. His punch-attack can't be toggled.

So you can either dole out to gear him well enough to survive whatever is beating on him, revert to medpacks and endurance stims and meditation, set manual heal hotkeys, or travel with a 'real' healer or healing companion. :/

on the other hand, he can be doing side-missions nonstop.